# mySQL Workbench: Query to update table based on data in another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, Table A and Table B that look something like this:

Table A structure:
id | name | statistic1 | statistic2

Table B structure:
id | name | datetime | round_info | statistic1 | statistic2

Basically, Table B records statistic1 and statistic2 for many different rounds, so there will be many unique entries with the same name, and I want Table A to be a master list where each name in B is represented as one row in A, where statistic1 and statistic2 in A are the sum of statistic1 and statistic2 for each round in B, respectively.

The script I need for this should get each name from Table B, check if it's in A, if it isn't, insert a default row with that name, then update it with the table B data, and if it is in A already, simply call an update on it as well.

I have this code which has some drawbacks:

```
UPDATE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT B.name, sum(statistic1) as s1, sum(statistic2) as s2
FROM B
group by name) as t ON A.name = t.name
SET A.statistic1 = t.s1;
```

It doesn't insert rows to A when a name in B is not in A, and it only updates one of the statistics at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.statistic1 = (SELECT sum(B.statistic1) 
    FROM B 
    WHERE B.name = A.name
    group by B.name )
```